# The code below only fills in one page of the excel worksheet. The color will be above filled into rows From A to Q

Tags: excel, vba

This code is to fill the row above the filled in rows. There are all the ranges required in the coding but it will only fill the 1 page in worksheet? rather than all specified ranges of worksheet pages.
I need activate all the ranges but it only activates the first range?
Please can somebody help. I could send the workbook over if that helps?

```
            Private Sub Fill_Color_Change()
       
            Dim Com As ComboBox
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            
            Set Com = Me.Fill_Color
  
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Card Master")

              With ws
                Select Case Com.Value
                    Case Is = "Fill Color 1 Page Job Card"
                        Color .Range("A13:Q61")
            
                    Case Is = "Fill Color 2 Page Job Card"
                        Color .Range("A13:Q61")
                        Color .Range("A66:Q120")
               
                    Case Is = ("Fill Color 3 Page Job Card")
                         Color .Range("A13:Q61")
                        Color .Range("A66:Q122")
                        Color .Range("A127:Q183")
                        
                    Case Is = ("Fill Color 4 Page Job Card")
                        Color .Range("A13:Q61")
                        Color .Range("A66:Q122")
                        Color .Range("A127:Q183")
                        Color .Range("A188:Q244")
            
                    Case Is = ("Fill Color 5 Page Job Card")
                        Color .Range("A13:Q61")
                        Color .Range("A66:Q122")
                        Color .Range("A127:Q183")
                        Color .Range("A188:Q244")
                        Color .Range("A249:Q299")
                End Select
                
            End With
            
            
            End Sub
            
            Function Color(Rng As Range)
            
            Dim row As Range
            Dim sheet As Worksheet
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Card Master")
            Dim EmptyRowNum As Integer
            
            For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
            
                Set row = Rng.Rows(i)
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(row) = 0 Then
                    EmptyRowNum = EmptyRowNum + 1
                End If
                If EmptyRowNum = 2 Then
                    EmptyRowNum = 0
                    row.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                End If
            
            Next i
            
            End Function
```

Comment: Are you asking that your function should be iterating over all the worksheets in your workbook?

Comment: No just Job Card Master Sheet

Comment: I believe the problem is your `Case` statement syntax is incorrect. Each case should be formatted as `Case "Fill Color 1 Page Job Card"` and so on. Drop the `Is =`.

Comment: I`ve done what you said but it`s jumping over the code.

Comment: Should it be as Case ("Fill Color 1 Page Job Card")

Comment: The parens are not necessary. Try a `Debug.Print Com.Value` right before the `Select` to check what your value of the combobox is before that section. Alternatively, you can step through each line (using `F8`) and monitor how the code is executing based on the values.

Comment: One of the columns has formulas in it stopping it from working how do we overcome this? Would it help to send the workbook to you?

Comment: What isn't working? Can you pinpoint a line/section of code that is generating an error or is not producing the expected result?

Comment: It goes down to the bottom of my first page then there is a 4 row page gap  Then after that it wont fill the color. If i take the formula away from the column P it works fine. There is no errors. Please can i send my workbook to you.

Comment: You don't need to send the workbook. When you mention "pages" are you referring to "tabs" or "worksheets"? What is the formula in Column P? Is there any conditional formatting defined for these sheets/ranges?

Comment: Pages are pages within a worksheet. Here is the excel vba code = ROUNDUP(RC[-8], 0) * RC[-1]. There is conditional formatting on the sheet

Comment: Does it work if you disable the conditional formatting?

Comment: Conditional formatting does not seem to matter. I`ve taken it off and it still does not work. I think it`s formulas in a column P that are messing things up

Comment: Okay, what happens if you remove the formula (just as a test)?

Comment: If i take away the formulas from column P it works

Comment: Then I believe your issue is likely using `COUNTA` to count the non-empty cells. Issues have been reported when looking at cells with a formula and it may not catch if the cell **value** is empty. Try replacing the `COUNTA` formula line with a call to the function from [this site](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/use-vba-to-count-non-blank-cells-in-a-column.32797/) and see what happens.